# What does the Caret over equal Sign mean

Tags: uml

When looking at UML Examples under "Association and Dependency" i came cross the "=^" sign. According to the document i am reading both visualizations are describing the same, but what does the caret over equal sign mean?

[image: Caret over Equal Sign]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an UML notation but mathematical. 
It means that the first visual represenation corresponds to the second visual representation.

[See wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%89%99)